# Making printer preferences permanent

Tags: windows-10, printing, default-settings

Windows 10 lets you set some printer properties/preferences before printing, via a dialog box. The settings can be saved to a file for later reference ("Printing Shortcuts").

Anyway, every time you restart the printing application (such as Word), the default settings are restored.

Is there a way to make new settings permanent or to select a settings file automatically ? Would be especially useful if it worked with fast printing (Print entry in the context menu of files).

I am not sure if these features are application and/or printer dependent (here, HP).

[image]

Comment: This is not Windows functionality. It’s the printer driver. Did you try going to “Printers & scanners”, changing the default properties there?

Comment: Is there a way to save different settings on the Paper/Quality tab as profiles for future use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you open the same screen through Control Panel (e.g. Start → Run → `control printers`) and not through the app, then you'll be able to set default printing preferences.

Comment: Yep, it works ! Thanks, you made my day, as did @DanielB.

Comment: +1 for showing how to get to that screen via the Run dialog box